# Dual boot Windows 10 & Ubuntu, also run Ubuntu in hyper-v?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, virtualization, hardware-virtualization

I dual-boot with separate SSD's for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Is there a way that I can virtualize the Ubuntu 16.04 SSD in Hyper-V or VirtualBox and still be able to dual boot?

Comment: There are tools that will allow you to take your physical box and convert it to a vhdx file.  You can then use tools to modify that virtual hdd so only linux is installed on it.  Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of being able to actually keep the dual-boot, so when I do things in the virtual box they remain when I actually boot in Ubuntu. Does that make sense?

Comment: My answer is the same.  There are tools that will create a virtual hdd out of your actual hdd.  You can then boot that virtual hdd.  Please note in order to activate Windows on a virtual HDD you would need a second license, which is the reason, I suggest you get rid of the windows installation on the VHDD.

Comment: I have two separate hard drives - one for Windows, and one for Ubuntu. So I can create a VHDD out of the Ubuntu hard drive and then run that in virtual box AND boot from it like I normally would? Do you have the name of the tool to do that?

Comment: If you perform some research on the subject you should find the tool with very little trouble.